# How to detect all Wi-Fi consumers and their signal strength on Windows?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, sniffing

I am trying to create an infrastructure which detects the approximate count of people in the different zones of the huge building for statistical purposes using Wi-Fi. Don't worry, it is going to be used only for legal purposes. At this stage, it doesn't matter if I am able to detect connected devices or all active.

I took several TP-LINK WR740N routers, installled dd-wrt firmware on this, and organized the WDS network by applying the same Wi-Fi settings. Now, I have several routers in the same network, they are in the same subnet, dd-wrt shows the signal strength for every connected device, but I cannot know the signal strength to the every router. Moreover, consuming devices seem to not switch automatically to another router until the signal is lost at all. So, this information is kind of useless.

Also, I have tried to sniff traffic using MikroTik RB951, but it doesn't help as well.

Is there any way to see **the list of all Wi-Fi devices in the coverage of my router and their signal strength**? It is ok, if it can be achieved either by using routers or laptop network adapter.

Comment: In regards to your weak clients staying connected. You might be able to forcible disconnect a client when signal strength gets below a certain threshold.  Then hopefully it automatically re-connects to a stronger one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn’t. Unless the Wifi client is actively sending out probes to query for a specific network or encourage routers to send their beacon, it is completely passive until it connects to a router. If it is connected, it will talk only to that router.

Getting a list of connected devices is as good as it gets. You could always lower the transmit power if you feel the range is too long.

Answer (score 0):

yes.  I just saw this posted somewhere the other day.

Run cmd
netsh wlan show all

It works great and you don't need any special apps.